# Sorting an array of three items

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that takes an input of a certain sales amount, and does some calculations based on three pay rate plans. One of the things I want to put in, is a way to figure out the median of the three plans. So if plan1 = 200, plan2 = 250, and plan3 = 300, I want the computer to know that the median is 250. If someone could help me with an algorithim, or a pre-built function, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: There is no such function in C standard library, so you probably want to come up with your own implementation for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int ra[3] = { plan1, plan2, plan3 };
std::sort(ra, ra+3);
return ra[1];
```

Could probably be done more efficiently -- then again if you're really lucky the compiler *might* optimize it for you.

Code that "should" be more efficient will probably be longer, for example:

```
if (plan1 < plan2) {
    if (plan2 < plan3) return plan2;
    // plan2 is the biggest
    return max(plan1, plan3);
} else {
    if (plan1 < plan3) return plan1;
    // plan1 is the biggest
    return max(plan2, plan3);
}
```

Another possibility:

```
void order(int &first, int &second) {
    if (second < first) std::swap(first, second);
}

order(plan1, plan2);
order(plan2, plan3);
order(plan1, plan2);
return plan2;
```

Comment: Q: How can one tell a systems programmer from an application programmer? A: A systems programmer assumes that all data consists of integers, even pay rate plans. :)

Comment: @Michael: heh. What actually happened was that I would normally write a template function, but figured that's overkill for a questioner who can't figure this out, and would cause more problems than it solves. Anyway, monetary values *should* be integers, albeit expressed in thousands of a penny ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, std::sort doesn't seem to be a valid function. I do have something called std::qsort, but it looks alot different.

Comment: @emufossum13: `std::sort` is in the header `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int median(int plan1, int plan2, int plan3) {
  if (plan1 <= plan2 && plan1 >= plan3 || plan1 <= plan3 && plan1 >= plan2) return plan1;
  if (plan2 <= plan1 && plan2 >= plan3 || plan2 <= plan3 && plan2 >= plan1) return plan2;
  return plan3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get messy, but it may help you think through an algorithm.

How can you order three numbers?  Start by comparing two of them, and then compare the third until you know where it's placed.  This will need a lot of if statements, but will show you the basic algorithm.  (You can also used any variety of sort functions, but since you only have three elements, it's worth thinking through)

```
int findMedian(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    if (num1 < num2) {
        if (num2 < num3) {
            // the order is then num1, num2, num3
            return num2;
        } else {
            // We know num1 is < num2 and num3 is < num2, but don't know 
            // where num1 and num3 go: num1, num3, num2 or num3, num1, num2?
            if (num1 < num3) {
                // now we know: num1, num3, num2
                return num3;
            } else {
                // num3, num1, num2
                return num1;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (num2 < num3) {
             // We know num2 < num1 and num2 < num3, but don't know where num1
             // and num3 go: num2, num1, num3 or num2, num3, num1?
             if (num1 < num3) {
                 // now we know: num2, num1, num3
                 return num1;
             } else {
                 // num2, num3, num1;
                 return num3;
             }
        } else {
             // We know num2 < num1 and num3 < num2, so num3, num2, num1
             return num2;
        }
    }
}
```

It's a good exercise to be able to think through all the paths an algorithm can flow, and this demonstrates that process.  Once you have the logic, you can, if you wish, make it more concise using the ternary operator (and taking out the comments):

```
int findMedian(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    if (num1 < num2) {
        if (num2 < num3) {
            return num2;
        } else {
            return (num1 < num3) ? num3 : num1;
        }
    } else {
        if (num2 < num3) {
             return (num1 < num3) ? num1 : num3;
        } else {
             return num2;
        }
    }
}
```

If we want to sacrifice readability, we can condense it further:

```
int findMedian(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    if (num1 < num2) {
        return (num2 < num3) ? num2 : (num1 < num3) ? num3 : num1;
    } else {
        return (num2 < num3) ? (num1 < num3) ? num1 : num3 : num2;
    }
}
```

Or, we can take it the final ugly step and end up with a single line:

```
int findMedian(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    return (num1 < num2) ?(num2 < num3) ? num2 : (num1 < num3) ? num3 : num1 : (num2 < num3) ? (num1 < num3) ? num1 : num3 : num2;
}
```